# Error creating stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

Im trying to create this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetExif 
(
IN @album VARCHAR(50), 
IN @pic VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

SELECT CAMERA, 
FSTOP, 
EXPOSURE, 
ISO, 
FOCALLENGHT, 
DATETAKEN, 
GPSLATH, 
GPSLONG
FROM EXIF
WHERE ALBUMNAME = @album 
AND PICTURENAME = @pic

END
```

I get this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@album VARCHAR(50),  IN @pic VARCHAR(50) ) BEGIN

SELECT CAMERA,  FSTOP,  ' at line 3
```

The select works fine.

MySql Serverversion is 5.0.51a-log

After removing the @s im getting this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html)? The parameter names shouldn't have `@` in front of them.

Comment: That was definitely an error, guess is was thinking mssql instead of mysql. However thats not the only error

Comment: You are missing a semicolon. You should read the linked docs.